# How do I align the cboxTitle below an image but vertical align it to top?

Tags: colorbox

I am using this example as a base for my work:

http://www.katehendrickson.com/colorbox/example2/index.html

In the below link, I managed to switch the position of the cboxTitle to the bottom in the CSS as it was conflicting with the controls at the top and did not look good when content forced it to 3 lines. However, when the text is only 1 or 2 lines, a gap appears above it.

http://www.katehendrickson.com/collection/bacci/2.shtml

How can I make it vertical-align but underneath the image for as many lines as I want?

Thanks so much.

- Paul Mycroft

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to change the following line from this:

```
#cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:-75px; left:0; color:#000; text-align: left;}
```

To this:

```
#cboxTitle{position:absolute; top:100%; left:0; color:#000; text-align: left;}
```

Comment: Hi Jack! That worked like a charm - thank you! It's in place and working fine: http://www.katehendrickson.com/collection/bacci/ - Paul Mycroft